# A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={}. If you want to run this job again, change the parameters

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am getting  below error while running spring batch application

A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.

I have tried below things and few times application will up but most of the time  it is not working

```
JobParameters jobParameters = 
                      new JobParametersBuilder()
                      .addLong("time",System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();

                    JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
                    System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
```

Code for executing process for each 5 sec. Tried to change it to 60 sec but same issue.

```
 <bean id="runScheduler" class="com.test.sync.RunScheduler" /> <task:scheduled-tasks> <!-- <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" fixed-delay="5000" /> --> <!-- fixed-delay use instead of cron post checking--> <task:scheduled ref="runScheduler" method="run" cron="*/5 * * * * *" /> </task:scheduled-tasks>
```

DataSource

```
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="queryProvider">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
                <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                <property name="selectClause" value="SELECT *" />
                <property name="fromClause" value="FROM TBL_CHANGE_EVENT" />
                <!--  include INpROGRESS AS -->
                <property name="whereClause" value="WHERE THREAD_KEY &gt;= :fromId AND THREAD_KEY &lt;= :toId AND STATUS in ('Not Started','In Progress')" />
                <property name="sortKey" value="EVENTTIME" />
            </bean>
        </property>


            <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            --given my DB details
            <property name="url" value=" " />
            <property name="username" value="" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>
```

Comment: if you see `parameters={}` it means that your parameter is not taken into account. Can you share a unit test or a runnable project to reproduce the issue?

Comment: please edit the question and add code there instead of adding it in comments. Can you share your datasource configuration? We need to know where Spring Batch is checking for existing job instances with the given parameters.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine As requested  i have provided details kindly check

Comment: Which job repository do you use?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine It's Spring batch

Comment: yeah which one? Is it the map based job repository or the jdbc based one? Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine It is JDBC based Job repository